# Multi monitor support in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

I hear that Visual Studio 2010 has "Multi-Monitor Support".  Yet now that I am using it, I see no difference from VS2008.

I still have to resize all my windows when switching from one monitor to two and back again.

Is there somekind of Profile or setting I am missing?  For example, Delphi lets you save desktop profiles that record where you like specific windows.  Switching from single to dual monitors is as simple as selecting a different desktop profile.

Is there something similar in VS2010 that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multi-monitor support refers to the ability for you to undock a code window and drag it to another monitor.  Try dragging on the tab of a code window into your other monitor.

ScottGu has an excellent blog post on this subject

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/31/multi-monitor-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just drag the editor tabs out and onto your other monitor and witness the glory.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2008 you could detach things like the solution explorer and put them onto a different monitor, but source code pages were forced to stay on one monitor.